How to multiply the same matrix with each row of a tensor?
I wanted to find coordinates of a cube after two (X and Y) rotations without loops.
The cube coordinates are stored as vertices:
cube_vertices = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                          [1, 0, 0], 
                          [1, 1, 0], 
                          [0, 1, 0], 
                          [0, 0, 1], 
                          [1, 0, 1], 
                          [0, 1, 1], 
                          [1, 1, 1]])

And i mostly work with edges:
cube_edges = np.array([[cube_vertices[0], cube_vertices[1]],
                       [cube_vertices[0], cube_vertices[3]],
                       [cube_vertices[1], cube_vertices[2]],
                       [cube_vertices[3], cube_vertices[2]],
                       [cube_vertices[1], cube_vertices[5]],
                       [cube_vertices[2], cube_vertices[7]],
                       [cube_vertices[3], cube_vertices[6]],
                       [cube_vertices[0], cube_vertices[4]],
                       [cube_vertices[4], cube_vertices[5]],
                       [cube_vertices[4], cube_vertices[6]],
                       [cube_vertices[6], cube_vertices[7]],
                       [cube_vertices[5], cube_vertices[7]]])

that I store to find intersections of these edges with plane. Rotator is given as rotations repeated 12 times for each coordinate of cube_edges, so i could multiply along 0-th axis of size 12 (number of edges) and 1-st axis of size 2 (two ends of an edge) for all the coordinates:
phi, theta = 0.1, 0.1
Rx = np.tile(np.array([[1, 0, 0], 
                       [0, np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], 
                       [0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]]), (12, 2, 1, 1))

Ry = np.tile(np.array([[np.cos(phi), 0, np.sin(phi)], 
                       [0, 1, 0], 
                       [-np.sin(phi), 0, np.cos(phi)]]), (12, 2, 1, 1))
Rxy = Rx * Ry

The shape of cube_edges is  (12, 2, 3) and shape of Rxy is (12, 2, 3, 3). The multiplication should act along first two dimensions (12, 2) for all 3x3 single rotations per point coordinates of size (3). I can't figure out how to utilize np.tensordot or someting like that for this purpose:
rotated_edges = np.tensordot(Rxy, cube_edges)

The resulting shape of rotated_edges should be the same as cube_edges (12, 2, 3).
Thanks!

The following seems to do what you're attempting (using the same array cube_edges):
phi, theta = 0.1, 0.1
Rx = np.array([[1, 0, 0], 
               [0, np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], 
               [0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])

Ry = np.array([[np.cos(phi), 0, np.sin(phi)], 
               [0, 1, 0], 
               [-np.sin(phi), 0, np.cos(phi)]])
Rxy = Rx @ Ry
rotated_edges = np.dot(cube_edges,Rxy.T)


Here's a little self-contained demo you can play with:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## setup
cube_vertices = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                          [1, 0, 0], 
                          [1, 1, 0], 
                          [0, 1, 0], 
                          [0, 0, 1], 
                          [1, 0, 1], 
                          [0, 1, 1], 
                          [1, 1, 1]])
edges = [
         [0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 4],
         [1, 2], [1, 5],
         [2, 7], [2, 3],
         [3, 6],
         [4, 5], [4, 6],
         [5, 7], [6, 7]
]
cube_edges = np.array([[cube_vertices[i], cube_vertices[j]] for i,j in edges])

## rotate
phi, theta = 0.1, 0.1
Rx = np.array([[1, 0, 0], 
               [0, np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], 
               [0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])

Ry = np.array([[np.cos(phi), 0, np.sin(phi)], 
               [0, 1, 0], 
               [-np.sin(phi), 0, np.cos(phi)]])
Rxy = Rx @ Ry
rotated_edges = np.dot(cube_edges,Rxy.T)

## plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
for pair in cube_edges:
    ax.plot3D(*pair.T)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
for pair in rotated_edges:
    ax.plot3D(*pair.T)
plt.show()

The resulting graphs I get:


Seems that tiling rotation matrices was not necessary. Thanks!

@Serge Exactly, the broadcasting that np.dot does what you were trying to do by tiling. And you’re welcome!

Does matmul work just as well as dot for the last multiply?

@hpaulj Yes, in this case it does

Here are two ways of computing this product (with Numpy 1.26):
rotated_edges_1 = np.array(
   [
       [np.matmul(matrix, edge) for matrix, edge in zip(rotation_row, edge_row)]
       for rotation_row, edge_row in zip(Rxy, cube_edges)
   ]
)

rotated_edges_2 = np.matmul(Rxy, cube_edges.reshape(12, 2, 3, 1)).reshape(12, 2, 3)

print((rotated_edges_1 == rotated_edges_2).all())  # True

